# How to reorder array in Python with / without Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In order to search correlations between products and categories and next visualizations (heatmaps) I need to reorder array using Python with/without Pandas or other libraries from this:

`Book Name,   Category 1,   Category 2,  Category 3,
 Django 101   Python        Web-Dev      Beginner
 ROR Guide    Rails         Web-Dev      Intermediate
 Laravel      PHP           Web-Dev      Intermediate`

into that:

`Book Name,   Python, Web-Dev, Beginner, Rails, PHP,    Intermediate
 Django 101   True    True     True      False  False,  False 
 ROR Guide    False   True     False     False  False,  True
 Laravel      False   True     False     False  True,   True`

Is there any way to do that? Data stored into .csv file and read by pandas.read_csv ()

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587782/creating-dummy-variables-in-pandas-for-python

Comment: Maybe add some information on what kind of objects are in the array? Is this an array of arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) function in Pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Book Name': ['Django 101', 'ROR Guide', 'Laravel'], 'Category 1': ['Python', 'Rails', 'PHP'], 'Category 2': ['Web-Dev']*3, 'Category 3': ['Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Intermediate']})

dummies = pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df[c]) for c in df.columns[1:]], axis=1)
df_new = pd.concat([df['Book Name'], dummies], axis=1)

>>> df_new
    Book Name  PHP  Python  Rails  Web-Dev  Beginner  Intermediate
0  Django 101    0       1      0        1         1             0
1   ROR Guide    0       0      1        1         0             1
2     Laravel    1       0      0        1         0             1
```

Or you can reset the index of the DataFrame to the Book's name:

```
df.set_index('Book Name', inplace=True)
df_new = pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df[c]) for c in df], axis=1)
>>> df_new
            PHP  Python  Rails  Web-Dev  Beginner  Intermediate
Book Name                                                      
Django 101    0       1      0        1         1             0
ROR Guide     0       0      1        1         0             1
Laravel       1       0      0        1         0             1
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have data like that:

`
Book Name,   Category 1,   Category 2,   Category 3,

 Django 101   Python            Web-Dev      Beginner

 ROR Guide    Rails               Intermediate Web-Dev

 Laravel          Beginner         Web-Dev      PHP
`

so it produces column duplicates

Comment: Does not work exactly right since categories can be mixed like that so it will produce more duplications

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Book Name': ['Django 101', 'ROR Guide', 'Laravel'],
'Category 1': ['Python', 'Intermediate', 'PHP'],
'Category 2': ['Web-Dev', 'Web-Dev', 'Intermediate'],
'Category 3': ['Beginner', 'Rails', 'Web-Dev']})`

Is there any way to avoid columns duplications?

Comment: @sergei It is up to you to define the categorization.  To ensure uniqueness across categories, you can prepend each name in the column with an identifier, e.g. cat1_beginner will be different than cat2_beginner.