# Handling ragged CSV columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file containing data: (just the first ten rows of data are listed)

```
0,11,31,65,67
1,31,33,67
2,33,43,67
3,31,33,67
4,24,31,33,65,67,68,71,75,76,93,97
5,31,33,67
6,65,93
7,2,33,34,51,66,67,84
8,44,55,66
9,2,33,51,54,67,84
10,33,51,66,67,84
```

The first column indicates the row number (e.g the first column in the first row is 0). When i try to use

```
import pandas as pd
df0 = pd.read_csv('df0.txt', header=None, sep=',')
```

Error occurs as below:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 5, saw 12
```

I guess pandas computes the number of columns when it reads the first row (5 column). How can I declare the number of column by myself? It is known that there are total 120 class labels and hence, guess 121 columns should enough.

Further, how can I transform it into One Hot Encoding format because I want to use a neural network model to process the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem, you can pass a `names=...` parameter to `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df0.txt', header=None, names=range(121), sep=',')
```

As for your second problem, there's an existing solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python) that uses `sklearn.OneHotEncoder`. If you are looking to convert each column to a one hot encoding, you may use it.

Comment: Its work! And I am trying to understand how to implement one hot encoder. :D

Answer (score 0):

I gave this my best shot, but I don't think it's too good. I do think it gets at what you're asking, based on my own ML knowledge and your question I took you to be asking the following

1.) You have a csv of numbers
2.) This is for a problem with 120 classes
3.) You want a matrix with 1s and 0s for each class
4.) Example a csv such as:

```
1, 3
2, 3, 6
```

would be the feature matrix

```
Column:
1, 2, 3, 6

1, 0, 1, 0
0, 1, 1, 1
```

Thus this code achieves that, but it is surely not optimized:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=range(121), sep=',')      

one_hot = []
for k in df.columns:
    one_hot.append(pd.get_dummies(df[k]))

for n, l in enumerate(one_hot):
    if n == 0:
        df = one_hot[n]
    else:
        df = func(df1=df, df2=one_hot[n])

def func(df1, df2):
    # We can't join if columns overlap. Use set operations to identify
    non_overlapping_columns = list(set(df2.columns)-set(df1.columns))
    overlapping_columns = list(set(df2.columns)-set(non_overlapping_columns))

    # Join where possible
    df2_join = df2[non_overlapping_columns]
    df3 = df1.join(df2_join)

    # Manually add columns for overlaps
    for k in overlapping_columns:
        df3[k] = df3[k]+df2[k]

    return df3
```

From here you could feed it into sklean onehot, as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ noted.

That would look like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehot = OneHotEncoder(df)
import sys
sys.getsizeof(onehot) #smaller than Pandas
sys.getsizeof(df)
```

I guess I'm unsure if the assumptions I noted above are what you want done in your data, it seems perhaps they aren't.

I thought that for a given line in your csv, that was indicating the classes that exist. I guess I'm a little unclear on it still.

Comment: Thanks for your help too. I am trying to understand how to implement one hot encoder. :D

Comment: From there you'd just do something like:


from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehot = OneHotEncoder(df)
import sys
sys.getsizeof(onehot)
sys.getsizeof(df)

Comment: Actually I am trying to perform extreme classification with the help of neural network. here is the data set: http://manikvarma.org/downloads/XC/XMLRepository.html (the Mediamill one)

Comment: And I change the class label column into one hot encoder format first.