# Get one-hot encoded H2OFrame

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o, shap

I'm using xgboost within H2O for a binary classification task. The dataset has several categorical features, to which the model applies a one-hot encoding during training.

Now I want to use SHAP (https://github.com/slundberg/shap) to locally interpret the predictions. For this, it would be nice to have the dataframe with the one-hot encoded columns and values. However, I seem to find no way to get this from the H2O model.

I could probably manually recreate the one-hot encoding, but maybe someone know a quicker solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have had a [ticket open](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3955) for this for a while, but we will re-visiting this soon due to increased demand for this feature.  For now, you will have to convert your H2OFrame to a Pandas DataFrame using the [`as_data_frame()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.as_data_frame) method and then apply one of the following [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39287161/5451344).