# how do I add new columns to a dataframe with values for a particular column having 0 and 1 values

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a  column in a dataframe with values as XS, S, M, L, XL and XXL.
What i want is to have 6 new columns in dataframe as XS, S, M, L, XL and XXL and each having a binary value referenced from the  column. Is this possible?

I attended a lecture in which the instructor used something similar to this but I can't really put my finger on how she did it or what was the method called.

Any help, whatsoever is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I one hot encode in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is called [One Hot Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

And it is super easy to implement using scikit-learn. Just try the following:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=['SIZE'], columns=['SIZE'])
```

here you will have to import sci-kitlearn first. Also 'pd' is the dataframe where you have the SIZE column. Give it a go.