# Change values in Pandas dataframe to one-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe in pandas of categorical data. Each column represents one timestep and each row one individual.

The dataset consists on the location of the individual on a given timestep. Locations are of this kind: 1)The person is picking someone 2) The person is at home 3) Person is at work, etc. There are 13 different locations

There are 720 columns representing timesteps of 2 mins (one full day in total).

I would like to transform these categorical locations into one-hot vectors. The problem is that a single row, may not contain the 13 different variables, so each row is encoded differently without a standard rule for all of them.

I also tried to do it manually:

```
old_l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
new_l = [[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
            [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]

df.replace(old_l, new_l, 
           inplace=True)
```

But I get the error `ValueError: cannot assign mismatch length to masked array`

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python) answer your question?

Comment: did you include {handle_unknown='ignore'} in declaration of your one-hot?

Comment: There are no unknown values in the dataset, is that what you mean?