# How do I apply dataset that has been One Hot Encoded by scikit-learn to do Decision Trees?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, one-hot-encoding

First of all, I would like to apologize if this is a no-brainer, but I am still relatively new at this.

I have a dataset that has around 2,000+ rows and few columns. The last column, is the label that I want to predict.

For example, the dataset kinda looks like this :

```
Habitat   Diet        Class     Family            Weight(kg)    Label
Land      Herbivore   Mammals   Bovidae           200.00        Cattle
Sea       Carnivore   Mammals   Balaenopteridae   2100.00       Baleen Whale
Sea       Herbivore   Mammals   Trichechidae      540.00        Menatee
```

The column label (which consists of the label) has been one hot encoded using Scikit-Learn and combined back to the original dataframe. Which looks like this.

```
Habitat   Diet        Class     Family            Weight(kg)    Label_0    Label_1  Label_2
Land      Herbivore   Mammals   Bovidae           200.00        1.0        0.0      0.0
Sea       Carnivore   Mammals   Balaenopteridae   2100.00       0.0        1.0      0.0
Sea       Herbivore   Mammals   Trichechidae      540.00        0.0        0.0      1.0
```

The column Label is dropped after that. But after that, I literally do not know how to proceed because this is my first time doing a practical approach on this subject.

I also have split them to train and test set (based on a internet tutorial that I followed).

But right now, when I try below, it doesn't work.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

It gives an error message below

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Value from one of the column'
```

How do I approach this problem and proceed properly to classification?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I one hot encode in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python)

Comment: @RoshinRaphel, apparently not because I already do the one hot encoding for the label column (that I targeted).

It's just how to proceed after that, meaning, how do I take all those new generated columns that are from OneHotEncoder and apply it in sklearn DecisionTreesClassifier().

Because usually the tutorial that I watched or read (like this one : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/machine_learning_with_python/machine_learning_with_python_classification_algorithms_decision_tree.htm),  the column that are targeted for predictions are only 1 column (usually column name label).