# Python: One hot encoding using reference list

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have data something like below:

| CANDIDATE_ID | Job1_Skill1 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | conflict management |
| 13 | asset management |

I want to add one hot encoded columns for each skill in table python and pandas based on the reference skill set(list).
for example if reference skill set given is
[conflict management, asset management, .net]
then my output should be something like below:

| CANDIDATE_ID | Job1_Skill1 | FP_conflict management | FP_ asset management | FP_.net |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | conflict management | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | asset management | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I could do it comparing row by row  but it does not seem to be an efficient approach. Can anyone suggest efficient way to do this using python?

get_dummies method gives output based on values in same column  but I need to compare values for a specific reference list to encode i.e. get_dummies can give encoding only for FP_Conflict_management and FP_asset_management and not for FP_.net
and also get_dummies will be dynamic for each dataframe. I need to encode based on specific list of skills for every dataframe
but I need to compare the values with different column for encoding hence it cannot be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I one hot encode in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python)

Comment: If your question is resolved, please accept the answer so it gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple workaround by adding reference list to the source data dataframe.

```
# set up source data
df_data = pd.DataFrame([[12,'conflict'],[13,'asset']],columns=['CANDIDATE_ID','Job1_Skill1'])

# define reference list with some unique ids
skills = [[999, 'conflict'],[999, 'asset'],[999, '.net']]
df_skills = pd.DataFrame(skills,columns=['CANDIDATE_ID','Job1_Skill1'])

# add reference data to main df
df_data_with_skills = df_data.append(df_skills, ignore_index=True) 

# encode with pd.get_dummies
skills_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df_data_with_skills.Job1_Skill1)
result = pd.concat([df_data_with_skills, skills_dummies], axis=1)

# remove reference rows
result.drop(result[result['CANDIDATE_ID'] == 999].index, inplace = True) 
print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: what if there are multiple columns. I still want single one hot encoded column per skill.
like 
df_data = pd.DataFrame([[12,'conflict','.net'],[13,'asset','python']],columns=['CANDIDATE_ID','Job1_Skill1','job1_skill2'])
I still want the same structure as your output.

Comment: just .net for candidate_i=12 should be 1 and not zero.