# How to use One hot Encoder in my code, without using categorical_features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

| Car | Model | Mileage | Sell Price($) | Age(yrs) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BMW X5 | 69000 | 18000 | 6 |
| 1 | BMW X5 | 35000 | 34000 | 3 |
| 2 | BMW X5 | 57000 | 26100 | 5 |
| 3 | BMW X5 | 22500 | 40000 | 2 |
| 4 | BMW X5 | 46000 | 31500 | 4 |
| 5 | Audi A5 | 59000 | 29400 | 5 |
| 6 | Audi A5 | 52000 | 32000 | 5 |
| 7 | Audi A5 | 72000 | 19300 | 6 |
| 8 | Audi A5 | 91000 | 12000 | 8 |
| 9 | Mercedez Benz C class | 67000 | 22000 | 6 |
| 10 | Mercedez Benz C class | 83000 | 20000 | 7 |
| 11 | Mercedez Benz C class | 79000 | 21000 | 7 |
| 12 | Mercedez Benz C class | 59000 | 33000 | 5 |

Above is my data frame and I want to Encode **"Car Model"** using one hot encoder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I one hot encode in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python)

Comment: @yudhiesh I tried locking up few examples like these but could not fit the same in may code. I am beginner and hence have lots of confusion.

Comment: Looking at your question again, what do you mean by not using `categorial_features`?

Comment: @yudhiesh categorical_features is an attribute used to declare which column to encode for the one hot encoder, while watching tutorials I found a lot of people using it but it throws an error now as it is currently removed from the latest python .

Comment: I have added in an answer without using `scikit-learn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can one-hot encode the categorical variables like so.

```
one_hot_data = pd.get_dummies(df.Model, prefix='Model')
df = pd.concat([df, one_hot_data], axis=1)
```

**Edit:**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

jobs_encoder = LabelBinarizer()
jobs_encoder.fit(df['Model'])
transformed = jobs_encoder.transform(df['Model'])
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed)
df = pd.concat([df, ohe_df], axis=1).drop(['Model'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for adding this answer but I have learned to use dummy variables and was also able to incorporate but since I am a beginner I wanted to learn about OneHotEncoder and incorporate it .

Comment: @DikshaNasa try the updated answer using `LabelBinarizer()`

Comment: @DikshaNasa please do accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()
dfle['Car Model']=le.fit_transform(dfle['Car Model'])
ohe=OneHotEncoder()
dfle['Car Model']=pd.DataFrame(ohe.fit_transform(df[['Car Model']]).toarray())
dfle.head()
X=dfle[['Car Model','Mileage','Age(yrs)']].values
```