# Invalid literal for int() with base 10 'Washington'

Tags: python, pandas, database, error-handling, integer

I'm working on a base that has 35 columns and 3047 rows. One of the columns is 'State' which consists of 50 states in the USA, and I want to convert that states into numeric values ,e.g. Washington is 1, West Virginia 2, etc.

```
df.loc[df['State']=='Washington','State']=1
df.loc[df['State']=='West Virginia','State']=2
.
.
df.loc[df['State']=='Arizona','State']=50
df['State']=df['State'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

I got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'Washington'.
Can anyone help me? What can I do to fix this problem? Do you know some other way to convert dtype object in int?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I one hot encode in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have dataframe like this:

```
           State
0     Washington
1  West Virginia
2        Arizona
3     Washington
```

Then you can use **`pd.Categorical()`** to convert it to codes:

```
df["State"] = pd.Categorical(df["State"]).codes + 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   State
0      2
1      3
2      1
3      2
```

Comment: It works, column State is converted but doesn't match other columns and rows, it seems like the numbers are randomly divided.