# Merging two identically-named columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1],'b':[0,1,0],'b1':[1,0,0],'c':[0,1,1]})
df.columns = ['a','b','b','c']

>>> df
   a  b  b  c
0  1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0  1
2  1  0  0  1
```

I want to merge those two different `b` columns together, like this:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  0
1  0  1  1
2  1  0  1
```

I understand that I could use `|` (OR) in a bitwise context to combine them, e.g. with `a` and `c`:

```py
>>> df['a'] | df['c']
0    1
1    1
2    1
dtype: int64
```

But I'm having trouble selecting the two individual `b` columns, because of this:

```
>>> df['b']
   b  b
0  0  1
1  1  0
2  0  0

>>> df['b']['b']
   b  b
0  0  1
1  1  0
2  0  0

>>> df['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']['b']
   b  b
0  0  1
1  1  0
2  0  0
```

Comment: You should specify some rules for the "join" (it is actually not a join). In this case, I interpret from the data that your columns only contain 0's or 1's, and that a 1 overwrites a 0. Is that all?

Comment: Yes @Ric. I want `b` to end up as `1,1,0` because the two `b`'s are `0,1,0` and `1,0,0`.

Comment: `df["b"].sum(axis=1).clip(0, 1)`? Or `df["b"].apply(lambda x: x[0]|x[1], axis=1)`

Comment: `df.T.drop_duplicates().T` if you wanna drop the extra B column

Comment: Nice @Chris - that's useful too. I do want drop the extra one.

Comment: Just curious as why you have duplicate column names in the first place?

Comment: @Quang - I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69994937/17242583) to a different question, and I discovered later that there were duplicate columns because it's using one-hot-encoding. I asked this question because I searched quite a bit and couldn't figure how to do it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have multiple groups of repeated columns, you can apply the same logic of [not_speshal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70008096/17120692) to each group using `DataFrame.groupby`.

```
# group the columns (axis=1) by their labels (level=0) and apply the logic to each group
df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum().clip(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `sum` and `clip`:

```
df["b"] = df["b"].sum(axis=1).clip(0, 1)

#remove duplicate column
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

Comment: The call to `clip` doesn't even seem necessary.

Comment: You will get `2` instead of `1` if both "b" columns have `1`

Comment: @user17242583 To keep the other columns use `df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum().clip(0, 1)` (group the columns by their labels and apply the logic to each group)

Comment: @HarryPlotter - That would make sense if there are multiple duplicate columns. Otherwise my way is much faster (28.5 ns ± 1.04 ns per loop vs 2.55 ms ± 112 µs per loop). My code also becomes much more efficient with larger DataFrames (with 1000 times larger: 30.3 ns ± 0.809 ns per loop vs 3.41 ms ± 206 µs per loop).

Comment: Yes, naturally it would be slower. But in the case OP wants to generalize the logic for different groups of columns.

Comment: I think I'll use yours @HarryPlotter actually, because, though I love this fast little solution by not_speshal, the duplicate columns will be arbitrary, so yours will work better for my particular case. Will you please put it in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Beside the answer suggested [by *not_speshal*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007961/merging-two-identically-named-columns-in-a-dataframe/70008096#70008096), you could also access the columns by index as follows:

```
df.iloc[:, 1] | df.iloc[:, 2]
```