# Creating a table in Python using values of another table as new columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot

I am working in Numpy and Pandas.

I have a table of loans with the features *country* and *sector*.

| # LOAN | SECTOR | COUNTRY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Loan 1 | food | germany |
| Loan 2 | telecom | italy |
| Loan 3 | auto | japan |
| Loan 4 | food | japan |
| Loan 5 | telecom | germany |
| Loan 6 | auto | italy |

I need to drop the duplicates by the sector and the country, ie. select the unique values of these 2 features, and use them as columns creating a table with boolean 1/0 if the loan is active in that country or sector, as follows:

| # LOAN | food | telecom | auto | germany | italy | japan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Loan 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Loan 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Loan 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Loan 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Loan 5 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Loan 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

So, Loan1 in the first table had food as sector and germany as country; then, in the second table it has 1 on columns food and germany and 0 on all the other columns.

It seems a pivot_table but I don't understand how I could put the 1/0 as values?
Btw, what's the easiest way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
out = df[['# LOAN']].join(pd.get_dummies(df[['SECTOR', 'COUNTRY']].stack())
                            .groupby(level=0).sum())
```

*NB. use `.groupby(level=0).max().astype(int)` if there is a chance that both columns can have the same value.*

Output:

```
   # LOAN  auto  food  germany  italy  japan  telecom
0  Loan 1     0     1        1      0      0        0
1  Loan 2     0     0        0      1      0        1
2  Loan 3     1     0        0      0      1        0
3  Loan 4     0     1        0      0      1        0
4  Loan 5     0     0        1      0      0        1
5  Loan 6     1     0        0      1      0        0
```

Alternatives:

With [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)

```
out = df[['# LOAN']].join(df[['SECTOR', 'COUNTRY']]
                          .agg('|'.join, axis=1)
                          .str.get_dummies()
                          )
```

Or with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
cols = ['SECTOR', 'COUNTRY']

out = (pd.concat(pd.crosstab(df['# LOAN'], df[c]) for c in cols)
         .groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()
       )
```

Answer (score 3):

In cas you use `sklearn`, you can use [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [('OHE', OneHotEncoder(dtype=int), ['SECTOR', 'COUNTRY'])],
    remainder='passthrough', verbose_feature_names_out=False
)
out = pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(df), columns=ct.get_feature_names_out())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  SECTOR_auto SECTOR_food SECTOR_telecom COUNTRY_germany COUNTRY_italy COUNTRY_japan  # LOAN
0           0           1              0               1             0             0  Loan 1
1           0           0              1               0             1             0  Loan 2
2           1           0              0               0             0             1  Loan 3
3           0           1              0               0             0             1  Loan 4
4           0           0              1               1             0             0  Loan 5
5           1           0              0               0             1             0  Loan 6
```

Comment: thanks! It works perfectly. I gave the solved flag to mozway because you can go straight with pandas without sklearn but I understand that for more complicated cases it's much better this approach.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is one-hot encoding. There's a great thread on how to get that from a pd.DataFrame() on this thread: [How can I one hot encode in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python)

Cybernetic's answer was pretty thorough

Edit: mozway's answer on this thread is exactly right -- the get dummy's is the pandas fxn for one-hot encoding, I believe they used the same one in the linked thread

Comment: thanks for linking the thread, very useful!