# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float) when a dataframe passed to TFDF random forest model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a data frame with 60 numerical columns (dtype=float64) and 1 categorical column (dtype=object). I resolved NAN, missing, infinite values before applying them to the TFDF random forest model. However, I get the following error, ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
So, I tried converting every column of a data frame to a tensor, which worked fine.

```
# Extract one column from the DataFrame
column_values = valid_data['column_name'].values

# Convert the column values to a TensorFlow tensor
tensor_column = tf.convert_to_tensor(column_values)
```

However, when I try to get the entire data frame to tensor or pass the entire data frame to the TFDF random forest model the above unsupported error occurs:
`data= tf.convert_to_tensor(valid_data)`

The data is very similar to the below link:
https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/penguins.csv

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `arr=np.asarray(data)`. What is `arr.shape`, `arr.dtype`?

Comment: arr.shape : (2700,64) and arr.dtype gives: length 61, dtype: object. Every column in a data frame is float64 except for the categorical column.

Comment: A dataframe with a mix of numeric and string (object) can't be made into a numeric tensor.  The numeric and category columns have to converted sepately.

Comment: You can also take a look at [pandas' one-hot encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python) to get numerical values. Especially for binary features like sex, you can use `pd.get_dummies(x, drop_first=True)` to get only one feature with True/False.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. How does the dataset (mix of numeric and categorical columns) in the below link work well with TFDF decision forests?                         https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/tutorials/beginner_colab

Answer (score 0):

TF-DF author here. It’s not easy to solve this issue without seeing the data, so I’m going to make a few guesses.

- Your categorical column may contain both float values and string values. This is not supported by TF-DF. You can work around this and just cast the entire column to string: `df["categorical_column"] = df["categorical_column"].astype(str)`
- Maybe one of your float columns somehow got assigned dtype object and it cannot be resolved automatically by pandas. Very often, this can be solved by setting `df["float_column"] = df["float_column"].astype(np.float32)`. If you’re dealing with pure numpy arrays (as in the second part of your question), `x = np.asarray(x).astype('float32')` should do the trick, see [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636087/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupporte) for details.

Note that TF-DF does support heterogeneous datasets out of the box. NaN / missing values are also handled natively by the model (see theses hyperparameters for details [1](https://ydf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hyperparameters/#missing_value_policy), [2](https://ydf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hyperparameters/#allow_na_conditions) to control how this is done) and categorical columns are also handled natively (details [here](https://ydf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hyperparameters/#categorical_algorithm). Importantly, one-hot encoding categorical columns will likely hurt model quality and is not recommended.

The only clean-up that’s necessary is getting rid of infinite values and make sure categorical columns do not contain float values:

```
def replace_inf(df):
    df = df.replace([np.inf],1e30)
    return df.replace([-np.inf],-1e30)
result_df = replace_inf(df.copy())
result_df["categorical_column"] = result_df["categorical_column"].astype(str)
tfdf_dataset = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(x, label="mylabel")
```

If you think there’s a bug with the `tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset`, please report it on the project’s [Github repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests).

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. 1. I have tried running TFDF model without categorical columns, it worked fine. 2. I have also tried the function replace_inf on the data with and without categorical column, it throws error: Type error: argument of type int is not iterable. Does it imply the dataset has some issues other than categorical columns?

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the data, unfortunately. If you can share a minimal reproducible example or, even better, the full dataset (publicly or with our team - contact info is on Github) , I'm confident that this can be solved.

Comment: I understand. However, I am in the state to not share the dataset in public. Do you think Yggdrasil decision forest on windows might be a alternative solution to the TF DF decision forest library?