# Correlation Matrix in pandas showing only few columns

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe with the following columns.
[image]
When I do correlation matrix, I see only the columns that are of int data types. I am new to ML, Can someone guide me what is the mistake I am doing here ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly observe and @Kraigolas states from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)

> numeric_onlybool, default True
> Include only float, int or boolean data.

Meaning that by default will only compute values from numerical columns. You can change this by using:

```
df.corr(numeric_only=False)
```

However, this means pandas will try to converte the values to float to perform the correlation, but if the values in the columns are not numerical, it will fail returning:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'X'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html), by default `numeric_only` is set to `True` in the `corr` function. You need to set it to `False` so it compares non numeric columns. Observe that the columns in your final results were the only ones with numeric dtypes.

This behaviour is deprecated though: in future versions of pandas, `numeric_only` will be set to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the non-numeric numbers to numeric values using [pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html).

```
df = df.apply([pd.to_numeric])
```

Also, convert all categorical data such as city name to dummy variables that can be used to compute correlation, as is done in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11587782/16367225). Essentially, all the data you want to compute correlation on needs to be either a float or integer, preferably all one or the other, otherwise, you're likely to have problems.